# Download blob url

Tags: download, blob

I am working on some chrome extension that detects when a user downloads a file, the extension block the download, sends the download URL to my server, the server downloads the file, scanning the file for virus and if it's ok sends it back to the browser.

all is good except in some cases. when the user downloads a file from his WhatsApp web chat I'm catching the download URL as:

`blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/6addcff5-671a-4369-8ead-232099b748c3`

but how do I download this blob? I tried to download like a regular link but it gives an error:

```cs
 using (var client = new WebClient())
      client.DownloadFile(theBlobUrl, filePath);
```

My server is written with C# so prefer a C# answer, but other languages would also be helpful too.

Comment: did you find solution ?